# Retrieve Network user Info in OS X

Tags: macos, active-directory

Active Directory is binded to Mac OS X. 
With $USER or $HOSTNAME or WHOAMI , not much info is extracted of network user.

The requirement is to extract the domain name of the logged in user. Also , Should be able to differentiate local users vs network users.

DSCL or dsconfigad does not provide user related details. Any inputs on this front to get domain name will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Using dscl you can list all the details of any account the Mac can see, regardless of where it is. Remember that if the AD account has been cached down for local authentication as a mobile account then it will be found in the DSLocal node, not the Active Directory one.

When building dscl commands it is often helpful to browse the Directory Services with interactive mode. That way you can determine the path to read by just using the cd and read commands.